# TYPO3 Update to 8.7 Template not working

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I try to update an Typo3 Installation from 6.1 to 8.7 LTS but i dont get the templates working.
What i did so far:

- Updated the core to 6.2 -> 7.6 -> 8.7
- Updated all the Extensions as possible

The old installation used Fluid Pages Engine but this is not available for 8.7. As far as i understand it, fluid is now included in typo3?

Backend is working so far. I can administrate users, Pages and everything i looked at. However, when i call the frontend, i get an Exception:

```
#1294587217: The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured. 

TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\ServiceUnavailableException thrown in file
...\typo3_src-8.7.10\typo3\sysext\frontend\Classes\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController.php    in line 2487.
```

I tried the solution from the wikipage and replaced the "setup"-Template information

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/typoscript/domain.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/typoscript/typoscript.ts">
page.stdWrap.parseFunc.short.i3 = <span style="text-transform:normal;">i3</span>
```

with

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
# Define output for typeNum=0, the default type.
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD!
```

Then i see "HELLO WORLD!". Now i stuck: what do i have to do to get the "normal" template working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TYPO3 7 and 8 both include the FLUIDTEMPLATE Typoscript object, but EXT:fluidpages is an external extension mantained by the fluidtypo3.org team.

As you wrote:

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
# Define output for typeNum=0, the default type.
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD!
```

You are defining that the PAGE object will contain only that simpe TEXT object.

A "minimum" configuration to use the FLUIDTEMPLATE object would be:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10{      
  templateName = Default

  layoutRootPaths {
      0 = Path/To/Your/Layouts/  
  }
  partialRootPaths {
      0 = Path/To/Your/Partials/  
  }
  templateRootPaths {
      0 = Path/To/Your/Templates/  
  }    
}
```

which means that you are using an Default.html template

to use different templates, you should also configure some backend layouts; assuming that you are using the database to store them the previous code could become:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10{      
templateName= TEXT
templateName.stdWrap {
    cObject = CASE
    cObject {
      key.data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
      key.override.field = backend_layout

      default = TEXT 
      default.value = Default 
      //these are the IDs of the backend_layout records in DB  
      1 = TEXT
      1.value = Default

      2 = TEXT
      2.value = Home
      //add other values 

    }
ifEmpty = Error
}

  layoutRootPaths {
      0 = Path/To/Your/Layouts/  
  }
  partialRootPaths {
      0 = Path/To/Your/Partials/  
  }
  templateRootPaths {
      0 = Path/To/Your/Templates/  
  }    
}
```

See also: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

If you need further help I could suggest you to join the typo3 Slack channel (subscribe here: https://forger.typo3.com/slack) and join the **typo3-cms** channel and the **fluidtypo3** channel.

Comment: Thanks for the slack-information. will ask rest of the questions over there. 
And: you where right. with the minimum configuration i got different messages, so for now i can move on.
What a mess...

Answer (score 1):

I think your typoscript file is not included in `ROOT Template`.

First of copy all typoscript in the `typoscript.ts` file and paste in the `setup.ts` in `ROOT Template` and after check the frontend. If every thing is fine then definitely your typoscript is not included on `ROOT template` and if this is not working then some mistake in your typoscript object